# Getting push is not a function populating an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have this function to populate an array:

```
var arrEmailID = [];

var emailSpan = $(_PeoplePicker).find('.sp-peoplepicker-userSpan');
var _sid = "";
if (emailSpan.length > 0) {
    $(emailSpan).each(function() {
        _sid = $(this).attr('sid');
        _sid = _sid.split("|")[2];

        arrEmailID.push("'" + _sid + "'");
        arrEmailID = arrEmailID.join(",")
    })

} else {
    alert("null");
}
```

First value is pushed success as this photo:

[image]

but when it try to push second one it return:

> Uncaught type error: .push is not a function

Answer (score 2):

use `arrEmailID = arrEmailID.join(",")` outside the loop,

```
var arrEmailID = [];
var emailSpan = $(_PeoplePicker).find('.sp-peoplepicker-userSpan');
var _sid = "";
if (emailSpan.length > 0) {
    $(emailSpan).each(function (){
        _sid = $(this).attr('sid');
        _sid =  _sid.split("|")[2];
        arrEmailID.push("'" + _sid + "'");      
    });
    arrEmailID = arrEmailID.join(",");
} else {
    alert("null");
}
```

Comment: Just to give more insight into the answer, hoping it would help: it looks like at the end, you want to turn `arrEmailID` into a comma-seperated string of the ids. The statement `arrEmailID = arrEmailID.join(",");` would return a string, so after the first iteration of the loop, you can't use `.push` on `arrEmailID` (because by that time, it has been converted into a String literal `firstID,` and not an array anymore. What you would want to do, is to push all the ids into the array, and only convert the result into a comma seperated string after that.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because of the following line in your code

```
arrEmailID = arrEmailID.join(",")
```

The above line returns a string and post this line `arrEmailID` is now a `string` and not an `array`.

For reference, [Array.join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

Answer (score 0):

`Array.prototype.join()` will return a `String`. 
So After `arrEmailID = arrEmailID.join(",")` , `typeof arrEmailID == "string"` 
For `String` There is no `.push()`. So you catch an error
The solution is mentioned in @Anfath Hifans 's answer: 
do `arrEmailID = arrEmailID.join(",");` after the looping

Answer (score 0):

You can write that code much simpler:

```
var arrEmailID = Array.from($(_PeoplePicker).find('.sp-peoplepicker-userSpan'))
.map(span=>(span.getAttribute('sid')||"||"))
//arrEmailID should be an array
console.log(arrEmailID);
//if you want a string you can do:
console.log(arrEmailID.join(","));
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are using **[`jQuery.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)** and you have join `arrEmailID` with `,` and assign same into that array inside of that array. So instead of inside of array put outside array.

**DEMO**

```js
var emailSpan = $('#_PeoplePicker').find('.sp-peoplepicker-userSpan'),
  arrEmailID = [];

$(emailSpan).each((index,el) => {
 arrEmailID.push(`'${$(el).attr('sid').split("|")[2]}'`);
});

console.log(arrEmailID);

console.log(arrEmailID.join(','));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important;top: 0;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="_PeoplePicker">
  <span sid="a|B|abc@abc.com" class="sp-peoplepicker-userSpan"></span>
  <span sid="a|B|test@abc.com" class="sp-peoplepicker-userSpan"></span>
  <span sid="a|B|ta@abc.com" class="sp-peoplepicker-userSpan"></span>
  <span sid="a|B|tessss@abc.com" class="sp-peoplepicker-userSpan"></span>
</div>
```

---

You can also use **[`jQuery.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/)** with combination of `ES6` to get achieve required result.

> The [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

```js
var emailSpan = $('#_PeoplePicker').find('.sp-peoplepicker-userSpan');

let result = $.map(emailSpan, el => `'${$(el).attr('sid').split("|")[2]}'`);

console.log(result);

console.log(result.join(','));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important;top: 0;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="_PeoplePicker">
  <span sid="a|B|abc@abc.com" class="sp-peoplepicker-userSpan"></span>
  <span sid="a|B|test@abc.com" class="sp-peoplepicker-userSpan"></span>
  <span sid="a|B|ta@abc.com" class="sp-peoplepicker-userSpan"></span>
  <span sid="a|B|tessss@abc.com" class="sp-peoplepicker-userSpan"></span>
</div>
```